# You know the name: [json] Bourne

Tags: discussion, tags

I've always had a pet peeve of people using the phrase "JSON Object" to refer to any JavaScript object which happens to be the result of parsing JSON. It's just an object people!

Now I see we even have a special tag, [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) which does nothing to combat this misunderstanding. The tag excerpt:

> A JSON Object is a textual representation of an object in JSON format as defined by RFC 7159 section 4; it is an unordered collection of name/value pairs (called "object members"), where names are JSON Strings and values can be any JSON value.

I am left wondering how this tag differs from the existing [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) tag, whose excerpt seems quite similar:

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a 100% textual data interchange format originally inspired by JavaScript objects. It is widely used in RESTful web services. Parsers for JSON exist in nearly all languages, and libraries also exist which can deserialize JSON to native objects or serialize native objects to JSON.

The similar [android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json) tag:

> JSON stands for (Java Script Object Notation). It is a simple and light-weight data interchange format that can be easily read by humans and machines.Android includes the org.json library which allow working efficiently with JSON. This provides easy parsing of JSON data and creating JSON strings

appears to be specific to Android.

I originally thought of making the three synonyms (namely, point [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) and [android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json) to [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)), but reviewing the questions, it appears as though there are many things out there called "JsonObject" or similar:

- the Android API exposes a [`JsonObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class ([241 questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject+android+-java+-javascript) both [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), but not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) nor [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)). These could be retagged [android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json).
- Additionally, there is a [`JsonObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) class in plain old Java as well ([195 questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject+java+-javascript+-android) both [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), but not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) nor [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)). These could likely be retagged with [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json).
- There is also a `json_object` class in a C library called json-c (2 questions tagged both [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)). It seems like these could be sufficiently tagged with [json-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-c).
- There is a `JSON_OBJECT` function in MySQL (there was one question tagged with both [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) without [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), and I just changed that one to [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)).

I'm sure there are likely others, but I should think they could all be tagged with [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) if the fact that they are using the notation format is important to the question.

I'm not sure what exactly the best approach here is, thus I am not calling for burnination, retagging, or synonymizing. I'd like to hear the opinions of others what the appropriate course is.

Comment: That pun though, you JSON of a gun!

Comment: Blame the language. There is a legitimate JSON Object in JavaScript. It is just not what 99% of users reference. The actual JSON Object holds functions such as JSON.parse(). Any other use of "JSON Object" is either a slight misunderstanding, or sometimes an indication that the object only contains data (as in no prototypal hooks or functions involved). Either way, regardless of if it annoys certain people, I tend to interpret the phrase json object as someone who is working with a parsed json string that is in object form and try to solve the actual problem instead of the semantic one.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that a "JSON object" is a useful term in languages other than JS, such as Python, where an object loaded from JSON is a much different concept from a "native" object; you might hear the term "JSON array" as well.

Comment: @pydsigner An array *is* an object in JS. Clearly someone needs to delete that silly jsonobject tag.

Comment: @Knu `is a useful term in languages other than JS` is the whole point of pydsigner's comment.

Comment: JSON is JSON, regardless of whether the question has to do with C, Java, Android, Objective-C or even Visual Basic.

Comment: @pydsigner I'm not sure what you mean. In Python, a string containing JSON data is a native Python string, when you parse that string (eg with `json.load`) you create a native Python object, either a `dict` or a `list`. True, the keys of a JSON-derived `dict` are always strings, but that's normally not an issue, and when converting a native Python object to a JSON string using the `json` module any non-string keys are converted to strings.

Comment: (cont)  OTOH, the JSON specs permit duplicate keys in a JSON object, whereas a Python `dict` cannot have such duplicate keys; the same is generally true (AFAIK) of the native objects that JSON objects are usually converted to.

Comment: I guess my point is that once a JSON string has been parsed into a native object it's irrelevant that the object was created from a JSON string / file. So why do we _need_ a  `jsonobject` tag?

Comment: because it's amazing to put everything into small boxes and put tags everywhere. and because some languages can have a lot of problems when parsing jsonobjects, it's good to have a tag for them that's not language specifical but that discriminates between json (the standard), and the problems parsing it's objects.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree with your analysis of the situation, but I don't believe that having two tags that mean the same thing is useful. It's not that I don't answer questions if they use the term "JSON Object". It's that the reasons for tags - categorization and searchability - are diluted when we have multiple tags for the same concept.

Comment: @pydsigner Indeed it is a useful term; I think I pointed out a couple of places where they are used. Unfortunately, the tag does not reflect that usefulness. It merely regurgitates what the JSON standard is, which is already well defined by the `json` tag. If the `jsonobject` tag excerpt or wiki mentioned anything about it being "the object which results from parsing a string in JSON format", I probably would have just edited it out of the JavaScript questions and gone on my way. Still seems ambiguous, however.

Comment: "Object" has a specific definition in JSON independent of Javascript, which the tag correctly describes. Whether or not it's useful, it does *not* "encapsulate a misunderstanding". For example, `[1, 2]` would be an object in Javascript, but it is not a JSON object.

Comment: @user2357112 and Lightness have made a good point that I phrased that incorrectly. I'll remove that text.

Comment: Furthermore, `json` tag should define clearly the difference between Javascript Object and JSOn (or include a llink to a really good anbswer about it ?). I got myself trying to explain that to newcomers qui sometimes already. I know that most of them won't have read the wiki tag, but some will do, and answeres will know that there is an explanation/link in the tag wiki to be used when we will see the case another time.

Comment: *the Android API exposes a JsonObject class* actually it doesn't. The "builtin" from org.json is `JSONObject`. `JsonObject` is from an external library, gson

Comment: @Walfrat The [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info) has that information: *Note that **JSON is not the same thing as JavaScript object literals.***

Comment: @TimCastelijns Feel free to edit the question for any technical inaccuracies you see. I'm not an Android developer. Or a Java developer for that matter. To me the important part was the fact that there was something in Android-land called `jsonobject` (whatever the spelling/capitalization) which could possibly be the source of confusion with that tag.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Are there any real uses for [android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json)? Why can't it be tagged with just [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) and the choice of the library left to people who write answers (they will probably use the built-in library anyway). Same deal with C/Java/JS/whatever-based JSON and even real JSON objects for languages where functions just happen to reside on an object named "JSON".

I don't really see any situation where you'd set a platform tag and [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json), and it will be significant if [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) is present or not. Or when you'd set [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) alone, but no platform and no [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json). I don't see any additional useful information that those `json-whatever` tags bring to question.

All tags mentioned in question that contain `json` except [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) itself should be deleted and aliased to just [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json).

Comment: Almost - when using JSONCpp in C++ I want the question to be tagged [tag:jsoncpp] for sure.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I think your answer captures the trend for these tags. I'll write up a [tag:burninate-request] for `jsonobject` and another for `android-json`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, is it that pecicular and unique? I can see how C++ libraries can be wildly different because there's no built-in analog for objects, but still...

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: If it's a question about the library called JsonCpp rather than about the language called JSON, then the tag [tag:jsoncpp] is correct. It may even be the case that the tag [tag:json] shouldn't be used for such questions. You wouldn't insist that people tag things [tag:computers] instead of [tag:windows] [tag:linux] etc

Comment: "the Android API exposes a `JsonObject` class".  I wonder if some people used the `android-json` tag to reference that.  If so, it may be more useful to rename the tag to `android-jsonobject` and update its description rather than to burninate it outright.

Comment: @jinglesthula, once again: how it is more useful than just android+json?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Because the AndroidAPI's JsonObject class is not the same thing as JSON itself.  If there are questions relating to that class, such a tag would help to identify them as such.  If there are no questions that involve that class, then it would make sense to not create it now, but allow its creation later if such questions are posted.

Answer (score 21):

I agree that this misunderstanding is incredibly annoying.

I don't agree that the [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) tag makes any reference to it whatsoever.

I do agree that the [jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) tag seems entirely redundant. We don't need it any more than we need a [textstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textstring) tag.

Comment: For those who need a summary - he means Burniate the darn thing.

Answer (score -2):

For me at least when I refer to terms like *JSON Object* and *JSON Array* even in javascript I'm mostly referring to serializable objects which in some cases they are not the same as **Object** or **Array**

Object

```js
{
    foo: 'Hello',
    're': /\w+/,
     date: new Date(),
}
```

Json Object

```json
{
    "foo": "Hello",
    "date": "2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I have a lot of discussions about making something a "JSON Object" or a "JSON Array", you could make the argument that once parsed they have the same **Type**, but in speech we refer to objects inside a JSON string as JSON Objects or JSON Arrays, and the entire string is just JSON.