# How can we disambiguate the tag [json-value]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [json-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-value) (currently 50 questions) seems to refer to the T-SQL built-in-function `JSON_VALUE` in most cases. However, there are lots of unrelated questions tagged with it. It currently has no tag wiki.

How should we proceed with this tag?

Comment: Tag excerpts/wikis have little effect on how tags are used. I suggest we make [json-value] a synonym of [json], and create [sql-json-value] if it's really necessary.

Comment: @oguzismail [json-value]->[json] would also be bad. As far as I can see, most questions tagged are related to sql server/tsql.

Comment: @TheMaster That's why I said *create [sql-json-value] if it's really necessary*. That way both [json-value] and [sql-json-value] would appear in the suggestion box (right?) and the asker would choose the appropriate one. And we'd retag the existing ones.

Answer (score 8):

Burninate the tag, or synonymize with [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql). We don't need a tag for every T-SQL function, and we certainly don't need any more confusion around [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) (*ahem* [You know the name: [json] Bourne](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327457/you-know-the-name-json-bourne) *ahem*).

If somehow the tag is deemed worthy of staying around, then perhaps renaming it [tsql-json-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql-json-value) would be appropriate.

Comment: I don't think synonymizing [json-value] with [tsql] is a good idea, hence the DV. The term is often used in a broader meaning, any value in JSON format (e.g `123`, `true`, `null`, `"foo\nbar"`, `[1, 2, 3]`...) can be referred to as *a JSON value*.

Comment: @oguzismail that is just JSON. Calling it "a JSON value" is meaningless.

Comment: Normally I'd synonym and be done but... in this case there's no single tag that fits well enough for a synonym. I tend to agree with oguz that it doesn't entirely fit [tsql]. I would say a straight burninate wouldn't be hard.

Comment: @VLAZ meaningless or not, people [do call it a JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22json+value%22).

Comment: The broader meaning does not require a tag. It would be nice if others answered instead of simply commenting on other's efforts to bring closure to the request...

Answer (score -2):

Let's add a tag wiki, stating that it is related to [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and drop the tag of all non-matching questions.

Comment: what about everyone that has a question about a json-value in any langue or environment that is not sql-server?

Comment: @Pizzalord then you're looking for a meta tag, and you don't need it

Comment: i think it is bound to be used a lot for things not related to sql-server because people do not read tag wiki's